# Link between the Grassmann algebra and spinors

Tags: group-representations, spinors, spin-statistics, grassmann-numbers, clifford-algebra

What is the exact link between spinors and the Grassmann algebra? I'm pretty sure there's one, based on the following:

- The Berezin integral in path integrals is done over the Grassmann algebra of $\Bbb C$
- There's a mapping from the tangent bundle of a supermanifold (which is locally $\Bbb R^n \times $ the Grassmann algebra), and the spinor bundle of a spin manifold
- On the other hand, spinors are defined just as the vector space associated to a representation of the spin group.

I'm not quite sure what the relation is. If we deal with spinors larger than basic Dirac spinors $\Bbb C^2$ (like a product of two spinors), are they automatically described by a member of the Grassmann algebra? Can it be shown that only those transform properly under the spin group?

Comment: An obvious link is provided by the spin-statistics theorem.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct link between the Graßmann algebra and spinors. The reason both are connected in physics is the spin-statistic theorem: The fields/operators associated to *fermionic objects*, i.e. Dirac spinors, *anticommute*, which is basically the defining property of the Graßmann algebra.

The algebra that actually controls the spinor representation - whose irreducible representation actually essentially *defines* what a Dirac spinor is - is the Clifford algebra, not the Graßmann algebra. *Quantization* links the two, see my and David Bar Moshe's answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282454/50583). The gist is that the defining relation of the Graßmann algebra is $\theta^2 = 0$, while that of the Clifford algebra is $\theta^2 = \hbar \eta(\theta,\theta)$ for the metric $\eta$. For a "fermionic"/anticommuting classical variable, the $\theta^2$ is the super-Poisson bracket. So precisely like the quantization of bosonic variables deforms the Poisson bracket by factors of order $\hbar$ and higher, the quantization of fermionic variables deforms the anticommutator, and consequently the Graßmann algebra into the Clifford algebra.

Comment: Isn't that link between supermanifolds and spin manifolds also true in the classical case, though? I don't think I've seen anything indicating quantization involved.

Comment: @Slereah You'll have to be more precise about what link you mean in order for me to answer that.

Comment: The exact theorem is (from https://arxiv.org/abs/dg-ga/9704002) : 
 For a spin manifold $(M_1, g)$ with a spinor bundle $\pi_S : S \to M_1$ and a supermanifold $(M_2, g)$, for every $p \in M_1$, there is a canonical isomorphism of $\mathbb Z_2$-graded vector spaces
  \begin{equation}
  \iota : T_p M_1 + S_p^* \to T_p M_2
  \end{equation}